# exception when running pyFlink batch processing with 2 sinks

Tags: bigdata, apache-flink, batch-processing, pyflink, flink-batch

I got the following flink exception when I run pyflink processing job:

```
Exception in thread read_grpc_client_inputs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 937, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 885, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 598, in <lambda>
    target=lambda: self._read_inputs(elements_iterator),
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 581, in _read_inputs
    for elements in elements_iterator:
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 426, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.CANCELLED
        details = "Multiplexer hanging up"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1664983018.802636895","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:44675","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":904,"grpc_message":"Multiplexer hanging up","grpc_status":1}"
>
```

the sink result is loaded with :

```
resultB = tableA.flat_map(name).alias('name') \
  .select(col('name'))\
    .execute_insert('allowed_table').wait()
resultA = tableA.flat_map(name).alias('name') \
  .select(col('name'))\
    .execute_insert('allowed_table').wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing `.wait()`